# How Silverlight code gets exceuted

Tags: silverlight

Can anyone please explain me how silverlight code gets executed.For example in asp.net if we request any .aspx page then browser makes a http request to the server and then at server level it goes through pipeline and at last http handler processes request and returns plain html to browser.What happens in case of silverlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great article [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=226)